# [Phonegap], Using html file for request and response how to hit the local application server

Tags: cordova

I am new user to phone gap

1. Just tried one example with one HTML, js & css file its working.
2. It is possible to run a apps more than 50 HTML files like a web application.
3. using phone gap apps can i get the response and request from local application server running in my system.

Please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to run apps with any number of HTML files but remember to convert the pages for effective rendering on mobile phone. You may look at JQuery Mobile to start with. If you are used to JQuery it is pretty simple to pick up.

You can run any url (don't use localhost), as long as it is accessible from your internet browser on phone, it will work from phonegap too. You will need to connect your phone to wifi network and make sure you either user ip address in the url or you run local dns server that resolves your machine name.

Comment: Ok Thanks but how can i get the request and response from local app server.